# Mac OS, Karabiner - Rebind a key to backtick on Hungarian keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I just received a MacBook with a Hungarian keyboard layout from my workplace to work on. Hungarian keyboards don't have a specific buttons for backtick, they instead start the numbers on 0, so I wanted to find out how to type it.

As I could not find an answer on how to type it, I decided to remap right command to it, as I don't use this key at all anyway - using Karabiner.

Karabiner mapping
[image: Karabiner mapping]

However even using this mapping, pressing does not produce a backtick, but this Hungarian character: í

Can you tell me a way to get a Hungarian Mac to produce a backtick character?

Comment: Try opt/shift/2 - that's what I get if I add Hungarian to my UK keyboard layout, though it starts as a dead key so I have to tap space if I want it alone. ` You can use the Keyboard viewer by adding it to the menu bar from keyboard prefs, or inside your language Input settings a smaller version of that. It's good for finding odd key-combos to dig out less common glyphs.

Comment: Seems like Karabiner is mapping to where it *thinks* it ought to be on an ISO keyboard, the key left of Z. It's only left of 1 on an ANSI [US] keyboard.

Comment: Hmm…I found it, but it moves, depending on whether you're set to Hungarian or Hungarian QWERTY.  Hungarian, it's on opt/ű and on qwerty it's on opt/shift/í

Comment: @Tetsujin Wow, it's really there on opt-ű. Thank you :) If you change your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a few minutes to track down, but tasks like this really benefit from using the Keyboard Viewer, accessible from the language menu.

Here, we find it lurking behind ü when you hold  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>

[image]